# Problems running Manning's Hadoop in Practice 4.1 MapReduce code on Hadoop 1.0.3

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am attempting to run the 4.1 example code from Manning's "Hadoop in Practice" at http://www.manning.com/lam/

I am running Ubuntu 10.4 using hadoop 1.0.3 java 6.

The examples from http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/, I used the wordcount example to verify the installation.

I then tried to running the 4.1 example using:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar MyJob.jar MyJob /user/hduser/4.1/input /user/hduser/4.1output
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

The public run method in the example that runs and manning's code appear to be different.

I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Give the complete path of the jar. For example, if MyJob.jar is present inside your home directory then : `hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /home/hduser/MyJob.jar MyJob /user/hduser/4.1/input /user/hduser/4.1output`

Comment: Tried suggestion "0", still same error message, ideas and thanks,

Comment: could the driver in hadoop-1.0.3 be that different then the one used in "Manning"?

Comment: Hi Tariq, sent U the code on your gmail, was not sure how to enter it on stack overFlow. thanks, Chris

Comment: sure sir..i'll look into it and get back to you asap

Comment: Do you have this class inside a package?If so, you need to provide the fully qualified name. For example, I created this same class inside the package org.mypack.wc, so I have to use the following command :
apache@hadoop:/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4$ bin/hadoop jar ~/WC.jar org.mypack.wc.MyJob /mapin/in.txt /mapin/in2.txt
If that is the case with you please make sure you have added the package name while issuing the run command. One small suggestion as well. The API which you are using is the older one. It is advisable to use the new API, which is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce

Comment: Also make sure that the jar and the directory holding the jar has proper permissions.

Comment: Can I use the older API with Hadoop-1.0.3? How can I get it?

Comment: you already using it sir."org.apache.hadoop.mapred" is the older API.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Hadoop 1.0.3.16 and java 6 but I managed to get the Manning example 4.1 working by adding `job.setJar("/path/to/MyJob.jar");` after `job.setJobName("MyJob");` I thought of making this change because I was getting a warning: `WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set`. User classes may not be found. See `JobConf(Class)` or `JobConf#setJar(String)`. Do you get the same warning Tariq?

I also tried adding job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class); instead but this did not work.

Cheers, Alex

Comment: I really apprecate the help, still not running. Anyone have any luck.